# Is there a better way to check these two variables instead of four ifs?

Tags: c

There must be two variables for example A and B, these two will either take the values 0 0, 0 1 , 1 0 or 1 1. I need to check these two variables and return a value between 0 to 3, is there a better way to this than doing four `if` statements like:

```c
if(B == 0 && A == 0){
  return 0;
}
if(B == 0 && A == 1){
  return 1;
}
if(B == 1 && A == 0){
  return 2;
}
if(B ==1 && A == 1){
  return 3;
}
```

Comment: Well, which combinations of values of `A` and `B` return which values between `0` and `3`? Be explicit.

Comment: Note, it's `if` and *only* `if` in C. Even though this is sample code, be extremely vigilant about every little detail. C doesn't care if you make mistakes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The four conditions you have shown could be addressed with the single line:

```c
return A + B * 2;
```

That is, of course, if the `A` and `B` values will *never* be anything other than `0` or `1`.

Comment: Simple math > tons of `if` statements.

Comment: @tadman I'm a simple kind of guy - I *like* simple maths.

Comment: This has two operators so it's basically multivariable calculus, but I'll allow it! 

Comment: This is so out of the box I love it, gotta think more like this, thank you !

Comment: Let the code do the work for you, make every line earn its keep. When you start to see repeating structures that's usually a sign you need to [DRY things up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) by approaching it from a different angle. Not every case maps to a simple one-liner line this, but when it does, it's usually a much better outcome.

Comment: For identical behavior to the original code, you could use `if ((A|B|1) == 1) return A + B * 2;`  -- only return if both A and B are 0 or 1; fall through if either has any other value.

Comment: personally, I prefer the `(B << 1) | A` route, since we're basically just mashing binary values together here.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yeah - I considered a *similar* bitwise/logical solution but decided that old-fashioned maths was probably simpler in terms of understanding.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Incidentally, the OP doesn't state what type the `A` and `B` variables are. The maths version will works for `float` and `double` (IIRC, IEEE-754 can store 0, 1, 2 and 3 *precisely*); bit mashing clearly won't work in such a case.

Comment: @AdrianMole You are technically correct.  The best kind of correct.

Answer (score 1):

@AdrianMole has already posted the obvious answer for this particular situation. But a more general solution could look like this:

```
const int ret[2][2] = {
    { 0, 1, },
    { 2, 3, },
};

return ret[B][A];
```

Not as clean as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66590544/6699433) but much cleaner than a bunch of if statements.